# How to check if the item in a nested list in a dictionary is a float?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently trying to do something like a calculator where invalid inputs produce an error. For the purpose of this exercise, each item in the list is split with a space. split( ) However, I am running into a problem if the input is a float.

I am unable to import any libraries

```
def get_valid_numbers(exprlist):
    for n, token in enumerate(exprlist):
        if token.isalpha():
            print(f"Invalid expression, expecting operand between {' '.join(exprlist[:n])} and {' '.join(exprlist[n+1:])} but {exprlist[n]} is a variable")
            return False
        if token != float and token not in '(+-**//)':
            print(f"Invalid expression, expecting operand between {' '.join(exprlist[:n+1])} and {' '.join(exprlist[n+1:])}")
            return False
    return True
```

I entered a float but it still returned the error message

```
def main():
    while True:
        expr = input('Enter expression: ')
        if expr == '':
            print('Application ended')
            break
        exprlist = expr.split()
        if get_valid_numbers(exprlist):
             eval(expr)
        else:
             continue
```

The expected output is that the program is to check if the token is not a float OR does not contain one of the operators and operands "(+-**//)". If it is a float or contains one of the operators or operand, it should return True

Answer (score 0):

Checking type should be done with `isinstance()`. For example:

```py
a = 5.4
isinstance(a, float)
>>> True
```

You can also check type with `type()`. For example:

```py
b = 2
type(b) is float
>>> False
```

`isinstance()` is the preferred method to use.

Comment: This works but i also want it to check if its an operator. So its something like if its not a float or not an operator "(+-**//)" then return the error message